# How to add setup node js in cpanel software section on alma Linux vps using WHM or terminal

Tags: node.js, cpanel, whm

I am facing a problem to setup cpanel. I have a vps on hostinger. In the vps I have installed alma Linux os with Cpanal. I have create a cpanel for a user but there the software section setup nodejs is missing. Now what I can do? How can i enable the setup nodejs in cpanel software section.

I have tried some away.
I have installed `mod_env` from apache module, `ruby27-build, ruby27_mod_passenger` from Ruby via Passenger, and nodejs 20 from additional packages. All are from Easyapache 4 software.